# centos 7 VM keep shutdown and restart automatically for unknown reason

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, debian, centos7

centos 7 VM keep shutdown and restart automatically for unknown reason.

I have checked my log messages, But I can't find what is the exact reason?. Please give any suggestions. I have attached my system messages below.

```
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Security Auditing Service...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 augenrules: /sbin/augenrules: No change
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 auditd[820]: Started dispatcher: /sbin/audispd pid: 833
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 kernel: type=1305 audit(1541972755.424:3): audit_pid=820 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 auditd[820]: Init complete, auditd 2.4.1 listening for events (startup state enable)
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 audispd: No plugins found, exiting
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 augenrules: No rules
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 augenrules: enabled 1
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 augenrules: flag 1
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 augenrules: pid 820
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 augenrules: rate_limit 0
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 augenrules: backlog_limit 320
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 augenrules: lost 0
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 augenrules: backlog 1
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Security Auditing Service.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target System Initialization.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting System Initialization.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Flexible branding.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Flexible branding.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target Paths.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Paths.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target Timers.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Timers.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Listening on RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target Sockets.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Sockets.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target Basic System.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Basic System.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started irqbalance daemon.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting irqbalance daemon...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started libstoragemgmt plug-in server daemon.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting libstoragemgmt plug-in server daemon...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting GSSAPI Proxy Daemon...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Resets System Activity Logs...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Login Service...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Load CPU microcode update.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Network Manager...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 rngd: Unable to open file: /dev/tpm0
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started OpenSSH Server Key Generation.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started ABRT Automated Bug Reporting Tool.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting ABRT Automated Bug Reporting Tool...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started ABRT kernel log watcher.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting ABRT kernel log watcher...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started ABRT Xorg log watcher.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Install ABRT coredump hook...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting System Logging Service...
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Software RAID monitoring and management.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Login Service.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd-logind: New seat seat0.
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd-logind: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd-logind: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Resets System Activity Logs.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started GSSAPI Proxy Daemon.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started RPC security service for NFS client and server.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started RPC security service for NFS server.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target NFS client services.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting NFS client services.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Remote File Systems (Pre).
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target Remote File Systems.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Remote File Systems.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Permit User Sessions...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started System Logging Service.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Permit User Sessions.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Job spooling tools.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Job spooling tools...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Command Scheduler.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Command Scheduler...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 438 (plymouthd).
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Getty on tty1.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Getty on tty1...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target Login Prompts.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Login Prompts.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 smartd[852]: smartd 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 smartd[852]: Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 smartd[852]: Opened configuration file /etc/smartmontools/smartd.conf
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 smartd[852]: Configuration file /etc/smartmontools/smartd.conf was parsed, found DEVICESCAN, scanning devices
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 smartd[852]: Device: /dev/sda, opened
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 smartd[852]: Device: /dev/sda, [Msft     Virtual Disk     1.0 ], lu id: 0x600224800d204937430c52b21cef22f1, 536 GB
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 smartd[852]: Device: /dev/sda, Bad IEC (SMART) mode page, err=5, skip device
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 smartd[852]: Monitoring 0 ATA and 0 SCSI devices
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Install ABRT coredump hook.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  NetworkManager (version 1.0.6-27.el7) is starting...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and conf.d: 10-ibft-plugin.conf
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Network Manager.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded settings plugin ifcfg-rh: (c) 2007 - 2015 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list. (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/libnm-settings-plugin-ifcfg-rh.so)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded settings plugin iBFT: (c) 2014 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list. (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/libnm-settings-plugin-ibft.so)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded settings plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2015 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  ifcfg-rh: new connection /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 (afc36ee0-5576-41ca-8356-85ae624af876,"eth0")
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMVxlanFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMVlanFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMVethFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMTunFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMMacvlanFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMInfinibandFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMGreFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMEthernetFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMBridgeFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMBondFactory (internal)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib64/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Networking is enabled by state file
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): new Ethernet device (carrier: OFF, driver: 'hv_netvsc', ifindex: 2)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): link connected
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (lo): link connected
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (lo): new Generic device (carrier: ON, driver: 'unknown', ifindex: 1)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 dbus[842]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' unit='polkit.service'
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 dbus-daemon: dbus[842]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' unit='polkit.service'
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 dbus[842]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1' unit='wpa_supplicant.service'
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 dbus-daemon: dbus[842]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1' unit='wpa_supplicant.service'
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Auto-activating connection 'eth0'.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'eth0' (afc36ee0-5576-41ca-8356-85ae624af876)
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting WPA Supplicant daemon...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Authorization Manager...
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): device state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 polkitd[906]: Started polkitd version 0.112
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 dbus[842]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 dbus-daemon: dbus[842]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Authorization Manager.
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 dbus[842]: [system] Successfully activated service 'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1'
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 dbus-daemon: dbus[842]: [system] Successfully activated service 'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1'
Nov 12 00:45:56 my01vps2018 systemd: Started WPA Supplicant daemon.
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 abrtd: Init complete, entering main loop
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  Policy set 'eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  (eth0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 dbus[842]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 dbus-daemon: dbus[842]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  wpa_supplicant running
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 dbus[842]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 dbus-daemon: dbus[842]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov 12 00:46:01 my01vps2018 nm-dispatcher: Dispatching action 'up' for eth0
Nov 12 00:46:02 my01vps2018 NetworkManager[850]: <info>  startup complete
Nov 12 00:46:02 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Network Manager Wait Online.
Nov 12 00:46:02 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Nov 12 00:46:02 my01vps2018 network: Bringing up loopback interface:  Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Nov 12 00:46:02 my01vps2018 network: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Nov 12 00:46:02 my01vps2018 network: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Nov 12 00:46:02 my01vps2018 network: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 network: [  OK  ]
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 network: Bringing up interface eth0:  [  OK  ]
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target Network.
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Network.
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Dynamic System Tuning Daemon...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking....
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Redis persistent key-value database.
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Redis persistent key-value database...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting ProFTPD FTP Server...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting NFS Mount Daemon...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 rpc.statd[1115]: Version 1.3.0 starting
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 rpc.statd[1115]: Flags: TI-RPC
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting MariaDB database server...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Reached target Network is Online.
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Network is Online.
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting LSB: Start or stop the Webmin server...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Crash recovery kernel arming...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting RPC bind service...
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Started RPC bind service.
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 systemd: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Nov 12 00:46:03 my01vps2018 rpc.mountd[1418]: Version 1.3.0 starting
```

Comment: There are no log messages here regarding the system shutting down.

Comment: Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Security Auditing Service.     
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...       
Nov 12 00:45:55 my01vps2018 systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, but journalctl doesn't show any other information either. Also, after the reboot, journalctl log simply contains the current boot information.

Answer (score 0):

That log doesn't contain any information of restart. You can check the information from Journalctl logs. That collect logs from kernel level.